# "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found" after Android Studio 4.0 Upgrade

Tags: android-studio-4.0

I am getting 'Default activity not found' after 4.0 upgrade. I can suppress the warning by changing default activity to nothing but that's not what I am looking for. I need to launch my app from launcher by default when I hit run.

My Manifest looks good(Merged manifest too). Can some one help me with a good solution for this?

Comment: Got the same issue. If you could post your manifest maybe the question will be re-opened.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with AS 4.0. More here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/158019870?pli=1